# Why is not possible to add a new 'key - value' pair to an empty JavaScript object with "for..in", but it works with a not empty object?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

Why is not possible to add a new 'key - value' pair to an empty Javscript object with "for..in", but it works with a not empty object?

If I write:

```
function test(obj) {

    for (prop in obj) {
       prop = 'a';
       obj[prop] = 'b';
   }
return obj;
}

var g = {};

console.log(test(g));
```

I get:

```
{}
```

If I write:

```
function test(obj) {

   for (prop in obj) {
      prop = 'a';
      obj[prop] = 'b';
   }
 return obj;
}

var g = {r : 'i' , w : 'o'};

console.log(test(g));
```

I get:

```
{ r: 'i', w: 'o', a: 'b' }
```

Why?

Comment: Analogously, consider: why is it that when I do `for(i=0; i<1; i++) { alert(1); }` my `alert` runs but when I do `for(i=0; i<0; i++) { alert(1); }` it doesn't?

Comment: An empty object has no properties for the `for` loop to iterate over.

Comment: If you try to do a `for(prop in obj)` on an empty object, that has no keys, it simply won't run. The `for ... in` is like a regular for loop, it iterates over the values. Why the other one works? Because your object has 2 key-value pairs, so it iterates over them, and actually sets obj['a'] = 'b' twice.

Comment: what do you think you would get instead of this object? I think I didn't get your point, the output is straightforward

Comment: if you iterate an empty object the loop won't iterate any time. that's why your first object remains empty

Comment: `for(i=0; i<0; i++) { alert(1); }`
your for loop doesnt run when since `i` is 0, and again 0 is not less than zero....

Comment: Thanks to all for your useful explanations!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the loop is never entered in the first case.

[`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The **`for...in`** statement iterates over the [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

Where is no property there is no iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In this:

```
function test(obj) {

    for (prop in obj) {
       prop = 'a';
       obj[prop] = 'b';
   }
return obj;
}
```

**When you pass empty object, for...in doesn't run even because object has no key so it returns empty object**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you perform the adding of the property within the `for` cycle. You are setting `g.a` as many times as the number of properties `g` already has.

In the first example, `g` has no properties, so you never perform the adding. In the second example you set it three times, you only see one new property in the end because each repetition overwrites the previous one rather than adding something new.